# Accessing sub-fields of Jira projects using python jira library

Tags: python, python-3.x, jira

I'm using `python3` `jira` library in order to manipulate `Jira` fields.
After having established connection to Jira:

```
main_jira = jira.JIRA(basic_auth=authentication, options=options)
```

where authentication and options are instantiated properly beforehand, I wish to be able to access sub-fields of `main_jira.projects()` but the expression `main_jira.projects()` does not resolve to an object that allows me to do anything useful. It has a handful of methods like `append`, `extend`, `clear`, `copy` etc.

1) How can I index a specific project by name?

2) How can I access its subfields with this python `jira` library?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1) Check out the documentation:

https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/examples.html#projects

**2.1.8. Projects**

Projects are objects, just like issues:

```
projects = jira.projects()
```

Also, just like issue objects, project objects are augmented with their fields:

```
jra = jira.project('JRA')
print(jra.name)                 # 'JIRA'
print(jra.lead.displayName)     # 'John Doe [ACME Inc.]'
```

2) Check out the documentation:

https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/examples.html#fields

Example about accessing the worklogs:

```
issue.fields.worklog.worklogs                                 # list of Worklog objects
issue.fields.worklog.worklogs[0].author
issue.fields.worklog.worklogs[0].comment
issue.fields.worklog.worklogs[0].created
```

if in doubt *check the documentation*